# How to get the machine Address when a miss in Emulated TLB happens?

Tags: virtualization, tlb

I am learning Virtualization and would like to know if anyone can explain in detail on how to get machine address once an emulated TLB miss occurs in x86. Also, how many memory access will happen in order to get the Machine address?

All the google search results gives very basic info. Please advice. Thanks.